# Como verificar se elementos de um array está contido em outro array JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso verificar se elementos de um array está contido em outro array?

**ex:**

```
array_1 = ['wifi', 'internet'];
array_2 = ['wifi', 'internet', 'telefone', 'email']
```

Como posso saber se os valores do array_1 contém no array_2 utilizando JQuery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Como fiz**:

> 1 - Percorri um dos vetores com o laço **for**.
>
> 2 - Depois já com os valores, utilizando o método javascript **includes** fiz a condição para testar se os valores de um vetor já existiam no outro.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var array_1 = ['wifi', 'internet'];
   var array_2 = ['wifi', 'internet', 'telefone', 'email'];

   for(var i=0; i<array_1.length; i++) {
      var array = array_1[i];
      if(array_2.includes(array)) {
         console.log('"'+array+'"' + " Existem em ambos vetores.");
      }
      else {
         console.log("Não existem elementos iguais!");       
     }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu entendi que você quer verificar se todos os itens de um array contém em outro array.

Você pode utilizar o [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro), onde o resultado dos itens encontradas serão armazenados em um novo array, com isso basta verificar se o tamanho desse array é igual ao primeiro array.

```js
function arrayCompare(first, last)
{
    var result = first.filter(function(item){ return last.indexOf(item) > -1});   
    return result.length;  
}    

array_1 = ['wifi', 'internet'];
array_2 = ['wifi', 'internet', 'telefone', 'email']

console.log(arrayCompare(array_1, array_2) === array_1.length);
```